# Route HTTPS traffic to different virtual servers on single IP

Tags: proxy, ip, reverse-proxy, https

I have Proxmox instance with single IP available.

I have multiple virtual machines for different sites (domains). Each virtual server have it's own https certificates inside them.

I need to find way to route https traffic comming to my server IP to different virtual servers based on domain name.

For HTTP traffic it's not a problem - just reverse proxy. But I need that for HTTPS and keep https certificates on virtual machines.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your current setup, there's really only one way you can do this, and I'm afraid you won't like it.

The issue is that you need to have something determining the hostname in the request, *before* passing it on to the appropriate server. Unfortunately, that pretty much includes handling the actual SSL connection - and that, in its turn, requires having the SSL certificates on that middleware thing. Which means you can't keep the certificates only on the the virtual machines.

The way I'd recommend going about it is to setup an actual business-grade load balancer, putting the certificates on that and having it route the traffic as appropriate.

The cheaper way would be to set up apache or nginx as a proxy on the public IP, and setting up one virtualhost per backend virtual server, and having that virtualhost handle the redirection. Those virtualhosts **will** need to have the SSL certificates of each virtualhost available to them. (I'd also set up some easily scriptable way of making the certificates available, so that you wouldn't have to manually edit each one, but that's outside the scope of this question.)

Comment: Problem here is that each virtual have it's own administrator.

Comment: @MartinMystikJonáš Hence the need for some scriptable way to make the certificates available. Unfortunately, there is no cheap and easy way around this.

Comment: Damn :-) I hoped for some solution based on SNI to just pass connection without actually handling it.

Comment: I don't think there is one at this point in time, not without shelling out a load of money anyway.